# How can I get schema from graphql?

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, apollo, graphql-js

I have a field [image]

There are values inside SignificanceLevelType :

[image]

How can I get these values in frontend if there aren't a special query for this?

When I sent:
`query { protectedNaturalAreas { edges { node { significanceLevel  } } } }`

I got significanceLevels in protectedNaturalAreas, but I want to get existing areas ('FEDERAL', 'LOCAL', 'REGIONAL')

```
`{
  "data": {
    "protectedNaturalAreas": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "significanceLevel": "FEDERAL"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "significanceLevel": "REGIONAL"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "significanceLevel": "REGIONAL"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`
```

I use Apollo and Vue3

Comment: Do you need to make an [Introspection](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Introspection) query to retrieve the enum values?  I'm not really sure what the images are trying to show, and possibly a plain-text extract of the GraphQL schema might be clearer.